# Trying to fetch text from a web element gives me a error 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

When i'm trying to fetch some text from a web element from this [Link](http://ae.bizdirlib.com/node/946273). I'm trying to fetch information such as company name/email etc. The code i have written is below. Each time i execute this code. It gives me a error.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlwt
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page
#browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com") # Load page

#links =[]
link = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("h2 > a")



#for link in links:
link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP)

companyNameElement = **browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix > div > fieldset> div > ul > li > span").text**
print companyName
```

when i put .text in the find_elements_by_css_selector it throws a error. How do i debug and go about it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should read the guide [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix > div > fieldset> div > ul > li > span")
```

returns an array/list of elements.

So,

```
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix > div > fieldset> div > ul > li > span")`[0]`.text
```

must work for you

Comment: IndexError: list index out of range error !! What could be the error ?

Comment: None of the elements in your website matches the selector `div.content.clearfix > div > fieldset> div > ul > li > span`

Comment: I'm trying to capture name of the company, email, phone number. from the website. What might be the correct css selector ? I was using this earlier somebody in stack overflow suggested to use css selector. `.content.clearfix>div>fieldset>div>ul>li>span`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use css selector. you can use xpath of the targeted UL(*in which whole data is contained*) and then give the path of the [li] (*so that it can take all li element within that specific UL*). 

**Like this:**
`browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='node-946273']/div[1]/div/fieldset[1]/div/ul[1]") .find_elements_by_tagName("li")`
*Hope it works in python*
**I can achieve the above result by using below code:**
***Note: It is in java, kindly convert this code to python.***

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/node/946273");
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 List<WebElement> link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='node-946273']/div[1]/div/fieldset[1]/div/ul[1]")).findElements(By.tagName("li"));

    for (WebElement link2 : link) {

        System.out.println("" + link2.getText());

    }
```

***Even you can pass dynamic xpath based on the url selected.***
**Output:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzGML.png

Comment: The problem is that i will want the fetching info to be dynamic. the fetching information will be performed on multiple pages. from the home page http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493. My code will do the following open a new tab, copy only the text of company, email etc  and paste it into excel. So in the xpath the numbers keep changing as the link is dynamic, that's why i'm thking of css selectors.

Comment: Still that can be solved by xpath, as each targeted page has same structure. There are two possible solution: First either dynamically parse url  and get id and then pass that id in xpath. Second way is bit easier just use this code: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/div/fieldset[1]/div/ul[1]") .find_elements_by_tagName("li")

Comment: browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/div/fieldset[1]/div/ul[1]") .find_elements_by_tagName("li") , this code is working for every page mentioned by you. As this code only focus on the ul at certain position.